# simple ide for php

Tags: php, ide

i try to use notepad++ but it don't show syntax of function. how can i solve it or may be any else simple ide? try to use eclipse\netbeans but this is big monsters

Comment: They are monsters indeed, but they do the work they should perfectly.

Comment: What's wrong with Netbeans? IMO it's really good.

Comment: i am using eclipse.. sometimes notepad++

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Note:** This is not fully featured editor like big ones out there but very useful for quick editing and beginners alike :)

Try this [STAR PHP Editor](http://www.starphp.com/).

> StarPhP is a freeware editor for PHP
>   and HTML. This editor is specially
>   designed to be a lightweight and easy
>   to use application. It contains
>   features for both professional
>   programmers and beginners.

**Features:**

> ```
> Tabbed multi-document interface
> Code folding
> Code highlighting
> File/FTP explorer
> Internal browser for preview (Currently using IE only)
> Favorites folders (Local and Remote)
> Syntax Validation
> Brackets highlighting (PHP blocks and HTML tags)
> Automatic code completion (PHP functions and HTML tags)
> Shows function signatures while calling functions
> ANSI/UTF8 document encoding support
> Windows/Unix/Mac file formats support
> ```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Notepad++ can show functions and parameter lists.

Settings -> Preferences -> Backup/Auto-Completion -> Check "Function parameters hint on input"

I also find [Geany](http://www.geany.org/) a very nice replacement for Notepad++ on Linux. It has function name auto-complete, and it shows parameter lists for built-in PHP functions. Very lightweight, even faster than Notepad++.

Answer (score 0):

Vim or Emacs will show syntax while you're editing. One or the other ought to be available for Windows, or you can get them with Cygwin. Pick one or the other; they both have fairly steep learning curves. You can use them as just editors, or they both have some IDE functionality. Emacs probably more than Vim.

Answer (score 0):

Notepad++ is a text editor and source code editor for Windows.
Notepad++is definitely my favorite Notepad replacement because of the extensive features that it has built-in.I have used notepad++ and it give me a useful result. The main thing that makes Notepad++ fit well with the Firefox metaphor is the self-update check capability.

[Magento Development](http://www.magentodevelopmentindia.com/)

Answer (score 0):

If you are thinking of trying emacs, the following link would be helpful.
http://prajwalaa.wordpress.com/2009/03/19/using-emacs-to-edit-php-files/

It shows you how to setup php-mode and how to do syntax checking in emacs.

Answer (score 0):

I tried lots of IDE. Phpstrom is the best one I ever have. auto complete for php html and javascript. also work with VCS like GIT or others. can do deployment as well. try it you will like it.